# Configure Eclipse to automatically place imports at specific place

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I would like to configure Eclipse's import feature to place import statements after a specific comment. 
Is it possible to achieve this through configuration or would I have to create some custom plugin, and where to start in that case?

Comment: You can configure a comment to go at the top of the file, before the 'package' statement. There is no configuration to add a comment between the 'package' and the imports. Writing a plugin to do this would require considerable knowledge of the workings of Eclipse JDT.

Comment: How to configure a comment to go at the top of the file?

Comment: Added an answer covering the file comment configuration

Answer (score 1):

You can configure a comment to go at the top of the file, before the 'package' statement.

To do this open the Eclipse Preferences and go to the 'Java > Code Style > Code Templates' page.

Edit the 'Comments > Files' entry to add the comment you want.

Also look at the 'Code > New Java files' section and make sure it is set to something like:

```
${filecomment}
${package_declaration}

${typecomment}
${type_declaration}
```

`{filecomment}` is the directive to include the 'Comments > File' comment.

There is no configuration to add a comment between the 'package' and the imports. Trying to put a comment here is unstable when you use Eclipse 'Organize Imports'

Writing a plugin to do this would require considerable knowledge of the workings of Eclipse JDT.

Comment: The thing is: I have a randomly generated comment starting with a known marker. This random part of the comment gets regenerated often during development. So the solution you proposed doesn't work for me. Can you recommend how to start with plugin development for this purpose?

Comment: Sorry but as I said such a plugin would require a lot of knowledge of Eclipse JDT, something I don't have. You could perhaps start by reading about the JDT [Abstract Syntax Tree](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html)